# I would like to add download functionality to my google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have put together, with the help of some online tutorials,a script that resides in my google sheet, that takes form submissions to generate my letter based on my templates.

Everything is working fine, but at the last part after saving out a PDF file I would like to add to the option to download the file with a pop up question.

"Would you like to download the PDF" [Yes][No]

I'm having trouble understanding how to implement it.

Here is my code without the download option:

```
function jobFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var jobType = e.values[1];
  var jobTitle = e.values[2];
  var companyName = e.values[3];
  
  var now = new Date();
  var day = now.getDate() +1;
  var month = now.getMonth();
  var year = now.getFullYear();
  var todaysDate = day+'/'+month+'/'+ year
  
  //determine which cover letter template to use based on the job type
  if (jobType == '3D Art') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1kENGdn8fALXPle28xHO2SCNsuHZiI1k4ckQhRlHJHoU');
  } else {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1lSrtlBvzvMiL6YAdSSAUiHvHPVG_DAsopQIo3nr6924');
  }
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1tS3CRWI2Vrh4RzS96n0I4lrktxLhCL6s')
  var copy = file.makeCopy('AndreaMele_Cover_Letter' + '_' + jobTitle + ' - ' + companyName, folder); 
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{todaysDate}}', todaysDate); 
  body.replaceText('{{jobTitle}}', jobTitle);
  body.replaceText('{{companyName}}', companyName);
  
  //Save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose();
  
  //Save out a copy as PDF
  var docblob = doc.getBlob();
  docblob.getAs('application/pdf').setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
  folder.createFile(docblob);
}
```

Comment: From what context is `jobFillGoogleDocFromForm` called?

Comment: Its added to my google sheet. That gets populated from a google form submitting.

Ex: I load form> fill it out> populates sheet> Sheet event trigger> runs script above.

Comment: Gotcha. As a workaround, would it be feasible to add a question at the end of the form which is something like 'Do you want to have a copy of the PDF emailed to you?' which then sends the PDF to them in the code *if and only if* they have said yes to this question?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're using `onFormSubmit` trigger. This action can't interactive with an user.

You can try sent to the user an email with the file or a download link.

Comment: Oh interesting, that might be kind of useful. On the "onFormSubmit" trigger, would it be possible to open a new link/tab with the new pdf link?

Comment: Nope. It's a server action. Users' browsers haven't access to this process.